# Plotting a heatmap based on clustering in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, clustering, data-mining, biostatistics

```
  id       sam1  sam2  sam3  sam4
 gene1       33    23    88    98
 gene2        0     0    99    95
 gene3       77   100    44    65
 gene4        0     0     0     0
 gene5      100   100   100   100
  :
  :
 gene20000   58    33    78    56
```

I have 20K genes (rows) and four samples (columns) which is given in percentage. Each gene is common to four samples. The hypothesis is, if any of gene has 100% in any of sample it is said to be present in that sample and if 0% it is absent. (For eg. gene3 is present in sample2 (sam2) and gene4 is absent in all samples.)

Since I have 20K genes, I would like to do clustering technique. Can I do biclustering and produce a heatmap? If so, please let me know how to do in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [pheatmap package](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=pheatmap%3apheatmap).  The link includes example code and images for clustering and displaying genetic data. It can apply a variety of clustering methods to your data before displaying them.

You should be able to get started with just

```
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(mat)
```

and then you'll have lots of options for adjusting the display and clustering parameters if the defaults don't suit you.